# Mysql create table composite/join of two other tables

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this is simple.. I'm just not seeing the correct syntax..

I have two tables:

```
select * from buyTable;
+---------+------+------------+
| Quarter | Year | buyerAgent |
+---------+------+------------+
|       4 | 2007 |          1 | 
|       1 | 2008 |          2 | 
|       2 | 2008 |          1 |
```

and

```
mysql> select * from sellTable;
+---------+------+-------------+
| Quarter | Year | sellerAgent |
+---------+------+-------------+
|       2 | 2008 |           1 | 
|       3 | 2008 |           1 |
```

This is what I'm wanting:

```
mysql> select ?????????????
+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
| Quarter | Year | sellerAgent | buyerAgent |
+---------+------+-------------+-------------+
|       4 | 2007 |           0 |          1 | 
|       1 | 2008 |           0 |          2 | 
|       2 | 2008 |           1 |          1 |
|       3 | 2008 |           1 |          0 |
```

The zeros can be nulls.. Don't care about.  It seems like this shouldn't be too hard, but I haven't managed to coerce mysql into doing what I want yet.

Update:

Using the two suggestions.. where a select was given for a left join, and a suggestion to use a full outer join.. I came up with the following.  In my case, buyTable and sellTable were mysql temporary tables. There's a condition on using temporary tables in mysql that you can't reopen a table for the same query.  So, I had to make a second temporary table for both buy and sell that had the same contents.  I called them buyTable2 and sellTable2.  If you are using actual mysql tables you won't need to do that, and can revise the following query appropriately.

Also, this query adds a third column that sums up the buy and sell columns.  In addition, it replaces NULL entries, where there wasn't any buy (or sell) for a given quarter with Zero.

```
(select buyTable.Quarter, buyTable.Year, ifnull(sellerAgent,0), ifnull(buyerAgent,0), 
        ifnull(sellerAgent,0)+ifnull(buyerAgent,0) 
  FROM buyTable 
  LEFT JOIN  sellTable ON 
    (buyTable.quarter = sellTable.quarter AND buyTable.year = sellTable.year)) 
union 
(select sellTable2.Quarter, sellTable2.Year, ifnull(sellerAgent,0), ifnull(buyerAgent,0),
        ifnull(sellerAgent,0)+ifnull(buyerAgent,0) 
  FROM buyTable2 
  RIGHT JOIN  sellTable2 ON 
    (buyTable2.quarter = sellTable2.quarter AND buyTable2.year = sellTable2.year));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick,

```
select buytable.quarter, buytable.year, sellerAgent, buyerAgent FROM buyTable LEFT JOIN  sellTable ON (buyTable.quarter = sellTable.quarter AND buyTable.year = sellTable.year)
UNION
select sellTable.quarter, sellTable.year, sellerAgent, buyerAgent FROM buyTable RIGHT JOIN  sellTable ON (buyTable.quarter = sellTable.quarter AND buyTable.year = sellTable.year)
```

Use UNION if you don't want duplicate entries, use UNION ALL if you want duplicate entries.

Comment: This works!  It has nulls for the zeros, but like I said, I'm totally OK with that.

Comment: Here's a bit more..    select buyTable.Quarter, buyTable.Year, ifnull(sellerAgent,0), ifnull(buyerAgent,0), ifnull(sellerAgent,0)+ifnull(buyerAgent,0) FROM buyTable LEFT JOIN  sellTable ON (buyTable.quarter = sellTable.quarter AND buyTable.year = sellTable.year);      will actually replace the null values with zero (and adds another column that sums the two, which might possibly be useful to someone out there at some point in the future)

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that this answer doesn't quite work.  The join being left causes it to take the full buyTable and add entries from the sellTable onto it... but it is missing the rows where there is a sell entry but no buy entry.  In this case, it doesn't have the 3/2008 row as part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select quarter, year, sellerAgent, buyerAgent 
from buyTable full outer join sellTable 
using(year,quarter);
```

Comment: that works in oracle. I should have read the question properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Jubobs True - but it does provide a huge clue